# onClick handler with jQuery - twice click?

Tags: jquery, event-handling, onclick

Is it possible to create an onClick handler on same element but with two other calls?

I mean:

When I click the button then alert `TRUE` will appear, when I click it one more time, `FALSE` text alert should appear, but when I click it one more time, then it should behave the same as first time clicked, so it should show the alert saying `TRUE` , one more time.

Is that possible (if so - how) to do with jQuery?

Answer (score 1):

What you are describing is a classic toggle.

Your JavaScript would look like this:

```
var toggle = false;
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#clickme").click(function(){
        toggle = !toggle;
        alert(toggle);
    }); 
});​
```

I've prepared a working JSFIDDLE example at this link:  [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/jAuEF/)

Answer (score 0):

```
var flag = true;
$('#button').on('click', function() {
  if( flag ) {
    alert('TRUE');
  } else {
    alert('FLASE');
  }
  flag = !flag;
});
```

***[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/68XSP/2/)***

#### Note

Wrap all jQuery code within `$(document).ready()` function.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach

```
​$(function() {
    var i =0;
    $('#btn1').on('click' , function() {
        if( i%2 == 0){
           alert(' TRUE !!');
        } 
        else{
           alert(' FALSE !!');
        }  
        i++;        
    });
});​
```

Working [FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/sushanth009/kFkdX/)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a way to do it with divs

```
<button id="clicker">Click Me</button>
<div id="true" style="display: none;">True!</div>
<div id="false" style="display: none;" class="firstTime">False!</div>​
```

Inside document ready:

```
​$("#clicker").click(function(){
    if ($("#false").hasClass("firstTime")){
        $("#false").removeClass("firstTime");
        $("#true").show();
    } else {
        $("#true").toggle();
        $("#false").toggle();
    }
});​​​​​​​
```

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/tutley/wdecQ/1/)

Answer (score 0):

Found this one:

```
$('#my-element').toggle(function(){
     alert("true");
}, function(){
     alert("false");
});
```